# Enthought Canopy --- error in using sklearn

Tags: enthought, canopy

I just installed Enthought Canopy on an Imac Os 10.6.8.
I get an error message (appended below) when I try to test sklearn.
The error is ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.
It looks like the wrong version of numpy is being used. I'm not sure how to fix.

### Rich

mu51220:~ rscherl$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Jun 14 2013, 18:24:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from sklearn import datasets
> > >       /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy/random/**init**.py:87: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'mtrand' does not match runtime version 2.7
> > >         from mtrand import *
> > >       RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 7 but this version of numpy is 6
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/**init**.py", line 32, in 
> > >           from .base import clone
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in 
> > >           from scipy import sparse
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/**init**.py", line 182, in 
> > >           from .csr import *
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 15, in 
> > >           from .sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/**init**.py", line 5, in 
> > >           from .csr import *
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 26, in 
> > >           _csr = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "/Users/rscherl/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_csr', fp, pathname, description)
> > >       ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I had in my PYTHONPATH (as defined in my .profile)
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages from where the wrong version of numpy was being picked up.
Eliminating this corrected the problem.